# reactjs onchange not work if change value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

This is my `reactjs` code:

```
<input name="date" id="date" value={this.state.listManage.date} onChange={this.handleForm} type="text" />
```

If I type in input, `onChange` work fine.

But if I used below code for change the input value, `onChange` not working

```
$("#date").val("data");
```

Input value change the to new value, but `this.state.listManage.date` not changed if I use jQuery

Comment: But why? Why would you change the value with jQuery in a React.js app?

Comment: Because I control the value from another button.

Comment: Jquery and React don't mix well at all, mostly because they have have pretty orthogonal approaches to UI. Jquery operates on the DOM, whereas it is anti-pattern to do direct DOM manipulations in React; React operates on its own virtual DOM.

Comment: When you need to change a value in component A from component B which they are separated components, the easiest way is using ```Context API``` or ```Redux```. Also it's possible to use old method. ( create a manual Tree and passing value and change function, as prop )

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps

install jquery

```
npm install jquery
```

loader.js

```
//loader.js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

Import the loader into your root file before you import the files which require jQuery

```
import '[pathToYourLoader]/loader.js'
```

After that the jquery will work as well

```
import '[LoaderPath]/loader.js'

...

const handleForm = () => {
  $("#date").val("data");
}

render() {
    return (
        <input name="date" id="date" value={this.state.listManage.date} onChange={this.handleForm} type="text" />
     )
}
...
```